# Managing fault types

Tags: c#, enum, constants

I have a `FaultType` `enum` with more than 100 members:

```
public enum FaultType
{
    FaultType1,
    FaultType2,
    FaultType3,
    FaultType4,
    FaultType5,
}
```

And I have a `FaultTypeConstants` `class` corresponding to `FaultType`:

```
public class FaultTypeConstants
{
    public const int FaultType1 = 600;
    public const int FaultType2 = 100;
    public const int FaultType3 = 453;
    public const int FaultType4 = 200;
    public const int FaultType5 = 300;
}
```

Now, I want to populate the `List<FaultType>` based on `FaultTypeConstants` values:

```
public static List<FaultType> GetFaults(List<int> FaultConstants)
{
    var faults = new List<FaultType>();
    FaultConstants.ForEach(fc => {
        switch (fc)
        {
            case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType1:
                faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType1);
                break;
            case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType2:
                faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType2);
                break;
            case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType3:
                faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType3);
                break;
            case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType4:
                faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType4);
                break;
            case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType5:
                faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType5);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    return faults;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you can't assign the `int`s directly in the `enum`, why not put it in a `Dictionary<FaultType,int>`? What possible reason could there be for splitting this into an `enum` and a `Class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to query the members of both types and match them by name. Something along these lines:

```
typeof(FaultCodes)
   .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
   .Where(fi => FaultConstant.Contains(fi.GetValue(null)))
   .Select(fi => (FaultType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FaultType), fi.Name))
   .ToList();
```

A way to speed it up is to build a map from code to enum. You can do this once in a static contructor:

```
public static class FaultLookup
{
    private static Dictionary<int, FaultType> _CodeEnumMap;
    public static FaultLoopkup()
    {
        _CodeEnumMap = typeof(FaultCodes)
                           .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                           .ToDictionary(fi => fi.GetValue(null), 
                                         fi => (FaultType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FaultType), fi.Name))
    }

    public static IList<FaultType> GetFaultTypes(IEnumerable<int> codes)
    {
        return codes.Where(c => _CodeEnumMap.ContainsKey(c))
                    .Select(c => _CodeEnumMap[c])
                    .ToList();
    }
}
```

The best refactoring was mentioned by slaks though: Get rid of the implicit mapping and assign the codes directly to your enum values.

In general: Try to accept the most generic collection type possible - this will give the users of the function more flexibility regarding passing in the arguments. I find nothing more annoying than having to make a temporary collection to satisfy some interface which expects a `List<T>` which might not even use the fact that it's a list.

"Be liberal in what you accept and conservative in what you produce" - I find that approach quite useful not just in data processing but also for interfaces.

Answer (score 10):

Get rid of the constants entirely and assign those values to the enum members themselves.
You can then use the enum everywhere.

You can cast an enum member to `int` to get its numeric value.

Comment: But that is not my requirement.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi: Why not?

Comment: list the requirement in your question please.